# How to make the Edit open in a different window DataGrid

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

I am making a GUI in aspx using a grid view for a database.  I was wondering if there is a way to hyperlink each row to edit in a different window?  I do not want the rest of the table to be shown just the row that the user wants to edit.  I also want the row to be in edit mode once it enters into the new window.  I have it now where it opens up the row by itself in a new window but the user still has to click the edit button.  Here is the code I am using for that.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
      <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkname" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>' PostBackUrl='<%#"~/editDetails.aspx?ID="+Eval("ID") %>' >
       </asp:LinkButton>
       </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

This does what I want to a point, however I want it to be in edit mode when it hits the new page.  Any ideas would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to open the editable record in a popup window. Just look at this example

[Master-Detail with the GridView, DetailsView and ModalPopup Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479344.aspx)

Otherwise if you want to do it your way, to open the editable record in new page, you can add DetailsView/FormView in your new page and show the record in an editable form.  Have a look at this example [GridView-DetailsView (Master/Detail) Control](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/GridViewDetailsView.aspx)

Comment: I am going to try this.  This looks like the best solution.  I have the AJAX downloaded and I am going to put it into my project to see how it looks.  +1 for the suggestion, and if it works good, give me till tuesday and the points are your.  Thanks Man!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" Text="Click Me!" NavigateUrl="javascript:openChildWindowWithDimensions('<URL>', '850', '625', false, false, true);"></asp:HyperLink>     

 openChildWindowWithDimensions = function(url, width, height, showMenu, canResize, showScrollbars) {
        var childWindow = window.open(url, "", "\"width=" + width + ",height=" + height + ",menubar=" + (showMenu ? "1" : "0") + ",scrollbars=" + (showScrollbars ? "1" : "0") + ",resizable=" + (canResize ? "1" : "0") + "\"");
        if (childWindow){
            childWindow.resizeTo(width, height);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I already have what I need poping up in a new window with the one row.  I need it to be in edit mode when it pops up.  thanks for your suggestion.